# Position a matlab figure generated in a GUI for automatic save

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I've been having some issues automatically saving a figure plotted in a GUI axes panel. Here's the code I have so far:

```
x= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = [10 5 6 7 8 20 5 4 3 8];

p = polyfit(x, y, 6);
r = polyval(p, x);

xlabel(handles.axes1, 'Time (\mus)');
ylabel(handles.axes1, 'Angular Velocity (rad/s)');
title(handles.axes1, 'Angular Velocity vs. Time (kT Test)');

aV = plot(handles.axes1, x, y, x, r, 'g--');

%Save figure
ftmp = figure();
copyobj(handles.axes1, ftmp);
set(ftmp, 'units', 'normalized', 'outerposition', [0 0 1 1]);
%Create file name
fileName = ['Test' num2str(time(1)) '_' num2str(time(2)) '_' num2str(time(3))]
saveas(ftmp, fileName, 'png');
```

The image is automatically saved, but it doesn't come out right. For instance, here is what the saved image looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the image is quite skewed. However, if I manually save the image, the entire figure is centered and saved. Is there a way to reposition the figure while automatically saving? 
(Please note that I'm looking for a solution that does not use `export_fig`).

I've searched this sight for a while, and none of the answers to similar questions have offered a solution to my problem.

Any constructive advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to create the figure in this way?  (ie using copyobj etc)?  If you just want a figure and save to a png there are far easier methods.

Comment: I have no particular need to do it this way. The only reason I'm using copyobj is because this is how I saw it done in multiple answers on this site and on mathworks. If there's a better way, I'm willing to try it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

```
x= [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10];
y = [10 5 6 7 8 20 5 4 3 8];

p = polyfit(x, y, 6);
r = polyval(p, x);

figure(1);
clf();

plot(x, y, x, r, 'g--');

xlabel('Time (\mus)');
ylabel('Angular Velocity (rad/s)');
title('Angular Velocity vs. Time (kT Test)');

time = clock();
fileName = ['Test' num2str(time(1)) '_' num2str(time(2)) '_' num2str(time(3))]

print('-f1','-dpng', fileName);
```

Not sure exactly what you want for your filename, so just made that up as I went.  The `time=clock()` is not needed if you want to have a different filename.

Note, too, that you can use `saveas(1, fileName, 'png');` as the last line.

Comment: I tried out your code. Unfortunately, my figure is still skewed when it saves.

Comment: Huh, it must be something to do with your setup then. I tried it on my computer and the resulting png file looks fine. No skewing. So, the problem is a shift to the right, right?

Comment: Does the image in figure(1) look correct or is it shifted too?  Is it just the png save?

Comment: Yep. I just recalled why I really used copyobj - the handle to these objects must be a figure. Since this is in a GUI, I have to copy the object into a figure in order to pass a valid handle to the function. I'm assuming this must be where the skewing is occuring.

Comment: But if you are getting a shift based on my code above, then I think the problem lies somewhere else. If you start a fresh Matlab and run my code above, there shouldn't be a shift.

Comment: Yes, your code is fine. It creates a centered png file, so it is something else with my GUI. Even when I copy the figure into the new object, I have to recenter the figure, otherwise it is off center before the save.

Comment: I'll probably go with export_fig. It works, but I wanted to avoid "bloating" an already large program with more file. Thanks.